# Memory buffer and IO operations

Tags: c#, performance, io

Are the following two code samples equal in terms of perfomance?

Code Sample 1:

```
var count = 9999999999;

using(var sw = new StreamWriter())
{
   for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
   {
      var result = SomeRelativeLongOperation(i);
      sw.WriteLine(result);    
   }
}
```

Code Sample 2:

```
var count = 9999999999;
var resultCollection = new ....

using(var sw = new StreamWriter())
{
   for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
   {
      resultCollection.Add(SomeRelativeLongOperation(i));

      if(resultCollection.Count%100==0)
      {
         WriteBlock(sw,resultCollection);    
         resultCollection.Clear();
      }
   }
}
```

I know that Windows uses memory buffers for IO operations. So, when I call the `StreamWriter.WriteLine` method, it first stores data in memory and then flush to the hard drive, right?

Comment: Yes, they're both equal in that neither of them compiles.

Comment: @Jon Skeet It's a c# pseudocode. Sure it's not compiles.

Comment: Pseudo-code doesn't have performance properties. Give *real* code, and we can talk about performance. Given that `StreamWriter` will always write to a stream, the performance will depend partly on what that stream does.

Answer (score 0):

StreamWriter is already buffered, so adding an additional buffer is simply going to make it less efficient.